# Inverse Function Integral

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-25}} \,dx$$

So I realized that there are multiple ways to solve the question above:

1. I could use the inverse secant identity: $\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} \, dx$, giving the final result in $\operatorname{arcsec}$
2. Or simply substituting $u = \sqrt{x^2-25}$, giving the final result in $\arctan$
3. Other possible methods that gives the final result in $\arccos$

**I tried using method #2** and got $$dx = \frac{du \sqrt{x^2-25}}{x}$$
Using this $dx$ value, I attempted to get the original equation in terms of $du$, but failed miserably.
$$ =\int \frac{1}{xu} \times \frac{\sqrt{x^2-25}}{x} \, du $$
$$ = \int \frac{(x^2-25)^\frac{1}{2}}{x^2} \times \frac{1}{u} \, du $$
which would not eliminate the variable $x$. So I was wondering what I did wrong, or could do better.

Also, would it be simpler to use method #1 in this case?

### Edit

So, after looking at the comments, I was able to get: $$\int \frac{1}{u^2+25} \, du$$
But I'm still lost on what should be the next step as this is still not integratable yet.

Comment: Did you try $x = \sqrt{u^2+25}$?

Comment: The integral, with this substitution, should simplify to $\int \frac{1}{u^2+25} du$

Comment: Your mistake was not simplify $\sqrt{x^2 - 25}$ when you are substituting $dx$, if you do it right, the integrand becomes $1/x^2$, and $x^2=u^2+25$

Comment: Suggest $x = 5 \cosh u,  dx = 5 \sinh u du. $                                           $$  t = \tanh \frac{u}{2}  , du = \frac{2dt}{1-t^2} , \sinh u = \frac{2t}{1-t^2} ,  \cosh u = \frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2} ,  \tanh u = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}   .  $$

Comment: Substitute $u=5v$ in the last integral you obtained then use $\int\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt=\tan^{-1}(t)+C$

Comment: @bjorn93 Okay, I was able to get the answer after substituting but may I know how did you get the value for u-substitution? ($u = 5v$)

Comment: @SWFS To integrate $\int\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\,dx, a\ne 0,$ you can use the substitution $x=at$. This transforms the integral to $\frac{1}{a}\int\frac{1}{t^2+1}\,dt$. In your example, $a=5$.